# How can I generate ECMAScript3 with Typescript in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, web-essentials

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Update 1 with the latest version of the Web Essentials 2013. I am also using Typescript.

How can I make the typescript compiler output ECMAScript3 instead of ECMAScript5? It seems that there was once a setting for this in the Web Essentials options under Typescript, but this option is now missing. Is there any kind of command line setting or settings file I can edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see that option under `project property page` : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2013/12/05/announcing-typescript-0-9-5.aspx

[image]

Comment: That makes indeed much more sense than one global setting in the Web Essentials add-in. Thanks!